# Continuous variant of KFG Inequality

Tags: inequalities

### Context

Let $t_1, .., t_n$ be jointly independent boolean random variables.

Let $X, Y$ be monotone functions (i.e. $\forall i: t_i \geq t'_i$ implies $X(t_1, ... t_i ..., t_n) \geq X(t'_1, ... t'_i, ..., t'_n)$.

Then, $E(XY) \geq E(X)E(Y)$

This is easily proved by induction on $n$:

- noramlize so that $E(X| t_n = 0) = E(Y| t_n=0) = 0$, expand

### Question

Do we know a continuous version of this? I.e. is there a way to prove this if the $t_i$ are continuous rather than boolean? If not, what is the simplest counter example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many variants of the FKG inequality.  For example, consider ${\mathbb R}^n$ as a lattice with partial order $x \le y$ if $x_i \le y_i$ for all $i$, and let $X_i$ be independent random variables.  Then for any increasing functions $f$, $g$ on ${\mathbb R}^n$, 
$E[f(X_1,\ldots,X_n) g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] \ge E[f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)] E[g(X_1,\ldots,X_n)]$
provided all the expected values exist.

See J. Kemperman, "On the FKG inequality for measures on a partially ordered space", Indag. Math. 39 (1977) 313-331 for more.